# how to use chart.js with knockout.js to create dynamic charts

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, chart.js

I would like to use chart.js with knockout.js to display a single graph with multiple datasets. I am not sure how to approach this using knockout.

Here is some basic code with HTML and ko.js init lines:

```
<html>
<head>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.1.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.1/Chart.js"></script>
  <title>Chart.js</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div>
    <canvas id="canvas" height="450" width="600"></canvas>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">

  function MainViewModel(data) {
    var self = this;
    var socket = io.connect('localhost:8080');

    self.lineChartData = ko.observable({
      labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July"],
      datasets : [
        {
          fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
          strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
          pointColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
          pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
          data : [65,59,90,81,56,55,40]
        }
      ]
    });
```

This code renders only static, pre-written data. Can somebody please help me and teach me how to change it so I can adapt it to have multiple datasets rendered on a single graph. Data is retrieved in JSON format from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Hope This will help You ...

```
lineChartData = {
  labels: [],
  datasets: [
    {
      fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
      strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
      pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
      pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
      data: [],
    },
  ],
};
// For Example You receive Data from API is Like this
data = [
  {
    month: "January",
    value: 1,
  },
  {
    month: "February",
    value: 2,
  },
  {
    month: "March",
    value: 3,
  },
  {
    month: "April",
    value: 4,
  },
];
    // Just push received data to labels and data to display dynamically
 for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    lineChartData.labels.push(data[i].month)
    lineChartData.datasets[0].data.push(data[i].value)
 }

 console.log('Month ', lineChartData.labels)
 console.log('Value ',lineChartData.datasets[0].data)
```